# Setting Postfix's sender_dependent_relayhost without a registered domain

Tags: ubuntu, postfix, email-server, amazon-ses

I've been trying to link up SES with my EC2 instance (that has no DNS record) and am trying to figure out how to jerry-rig my `sender_dependent_relayhost`. Since I do NOT have a DNS record that associates to my ip, is it possible for me to use my servers ip instead of my DNS?

I figure my sender_dependent_relayhost config would look like the following

```
$ cat /etc/postfix/sender_dependent_relayhost:
user@someip                   127.0.0.1:1125
```

Will this work ok in lieu of entering a qualified domain name?

I am following the setup from this link [Postfix with AWS-SES](http://www.millcreeksys.com/how-to-configure-your-postfix-server-to-relay-email-through-amazon-simple-email-service-ses/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The table used by `sender_dependent_relayhost_maps` is same format with table in transport_maps. So, using IP address instead a FQDN was valid.

The [official documentation](http://www.postfix.org/transport.5.html) that you require to surround the IP address with **[]**.

> The  interpretation of the nexthop field is transport dependent. In the case of SMTP, specify a service on a non-default port as  host:service, and disable MX (mail exchanger) DNS lookups with [host] or [host]:port. **The [] form is required when you specify an IP  address  instead  of  a hostname**.